# Apply color theme assigned to Java files to Apex(.cls) files in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to apply the colors defined for the Java files in my currently selected VSCode theme to Apex(.cls) files too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this setting

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.cls": "java"
  },
```